# How can I delete an element in list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I was practicing my grip on dictionaries and then I came across this problem.
I created a dictionary with a few keys and some keys have multiple values which were assigned using lists.

eg:

```
mypouch = {
    'writing_stationery': ['Pens', 'Pencils'],
    'gadgets': ['calculator', 'Watch'], 
    'Documents': ['ID Card', 'Hall Ticket'], 
    'Misc': ['Eraser', 'Sharpener', 'Sticky Notes']
}
```

I want to delete a specific item 'Eraser'.

Usually I can just use pop or del function but the element is in a list.
I want the output for misc as `'Misc':['Sharpener', 'Sticky Notes']`
What are the possible solutions for this kind of a problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
mypouch['Misc'].remove('Eraser')
```

Or, use a set rather than a list:

```
for k in mypouch:
  mypouch[k] = set(mypouch[k])
```

then, it is easy and O(1) to remove an element in a set, using the same code as the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 4 ways to do it the best is with `remove` but maybe you want to know different approaches

You can use `filter`

```
mypouch['Misc'] = list(filter(lambda x: x!='Eraser', mypouch['Misc']))
```

or short for with if

```
mypouch['Misc'] = [x for x in mypouch['Misc'] if x != 'Eraser']
```

or build-in function list `remove`

```
mypouch['Misc'].remove('Eraser')
```

or you can use `pop` and `index` combo

```
mypouch['Misc'].pop(mypouch['Misc'].index('Eraser'))
```